# Using apply with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this work...:

```
$('.foo').hide()
```

...and this doesn't?:

```
$('.foo').hide.apply(this,[])
```

I'm trying to write a function that passes arguments into hide().

Comment: I'm not really a JQuery master, but all examples off extending hide by using apply were made by using jQuery.fn. Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong object, `this` should be the element you want to hide.

```
$.fn.hide.apply($('.foo'), []);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/DkS4t/).

Comment: Which is exactly the same as `$('.foo').hide()` (except for being more to type and a lot more to process). And `this` is not "context".

Comment: @RobG I agree with you on both stances! :)

Comment: Ah yes... that's what I was missing. This syntax means I can fully wrap hide in my function. Even better I can even abstract it further with `$()[f].apply($(sel), options)` since the method's user may prefer hiding it another way. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add: no need to create new jQuery object with $(), you can reference hide method with $.fn.hide.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously because of the wrong context. It should be:

```
$.fn.hide.apply($('#hlogo'), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the following code:

```
  var newhide = jQuery.fn.hide;
  jQuery.fn.hide = function() {
    console.log(this, arguments);
    return newhide.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery hide already accepts arguments [as per the doc](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  And, you can pass those arguments like this:

```
$('.foo').hide(duration, fn);
```

If you were making your own jQuery methods, then there's a jQuery framework already in place for jQuery methods.  `this` will be set to the jQuery object and any arguments passed with the function will be in place.

Can you explain why you're trying to do what you're doing because it isn't making sense to me.